# Can't redirect multiple shell statements to named pipe

Tags: shell, named-pipes, io-redirection

Observe what happens when I issue two commands one after another, as opposed to on a single line, separated by a semicolon:

**Make pipe and launch movie:**

```
$ mkfifo pipe1
$ tail -f /dev/null > pipe1 &
$ cat pipe1 | omxplayer /path/to/video.mp4
```

**Exit Trial 1:**

```
$ echo -n q > pipe1; # Exits movie, but omxplayer hangs
$ echo > pipe1; # Completes exit process
```

**Exit Trial 2:**

```
$ echo -n q > pipe1; echo > pipe1 # Does nothing
```

**Exit Trial 3:**

```
$ echo -n q > pipe1; sleep 1; echo > pipe1 # Works just like trial 1
```

Could someone provide an explanation of why trial 2 does nothing. Also, is there a better way of issuing the quit command via the named pipe which does not require two `echo` statements?

Comment: Easy fix if your goal is to run two commands with output to a FIFO without closing the FIFO between them: `{ foo; bar; } >pipe`. However, from the behavior you're describing, it sounds like omxplayer may _require_ you to close the FIFO.

Comment: ...by the way, `echo -n` is not POSIX-standard (nor is `echo -E`). Better to use `printf`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the last writer on the fifo dies and the reader checks the fifo, it sees an end-of-file. If there is again a new writer before the reader checks, there is no end-of-file seen by the reader.  I guess your reader (omxplayer) checks for end-of-file.

To put it from the perspective of the reader `omxplayer`: it sees

1. `"q" EOF ... <LF> EOF`
2. `"q"` (`EOF` probably not seen by `omxplayer`) `<LF> EOF`
3. `"q" EOF ... <LF> EOF`

What happens is entirely up to how `omxplayer` processes this, and not a matter of you, the operating system or your shell messing it up.

Comment: thanks, but I don't quite follow what you mean by: *last writer*, *fifo dies*, *new writer before reader checks*, *end of file*...basically everything =P

Comment: Your `echo` commands write to the pipe, the fifo. Since they are separate commands run as child processes by your shell, they terminate (die). The reader is `omxplayer`, who is checking if there is data available in the fifo.

Comment: Oh, you mean maybe the inputs are coming in faster than they can be processed?

Comment: Not really; I guess it simply a matter of how this `omxplayer` processes its input. I guess there is some timeout involved in that program, which changes its behaviour depending on the timing of your input.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect buffering is involved somehow. Both (1) and (3) provide some relatively long period of time between the `q` and the linefeed, stopping the movie but not exiting until it has read a full line. In (2), the `q` and linefeed are so close together, that perhaps `omxplayer` is just ignoring the entire string. What does `echo q > pipe1` (which is similar to (2), but even faster) do?

Comment: `echo q > pipe1` does not work (hence why I made the move to `echo -n q > pipe1`...basically I was hacking what I did not understand)

Comment: Yeah, it's not clear to me either what `omxplayer` is doing with standard input that you have to prevent `echo` from sending a newline. Try `cat -u pipe1 | omxplayer /path/to/video.mp4`, which will disable buffering, and perhaps allow `omxplayer` to exit after you press `q` without requiring the follow-up `echo > pipe1`.

Comment: Oh, I think the reason is that omxplayer accpets a single keystroke only (ie. you press `q` not `q` and `ENTER`)

Comment: There is no buffering, at least not in userland, because there are multiple writer processes involved.

Answer (score 1):

`omxplayer` *is* a little bit picky on its (command) input. It doesn't like a command (e.g. `q` ) to be terminated with a newline `'\n'`. *A newline will be incorrectly handled by making it a part of the command (`'q''\n'`), resulting in an unknown command (whereas only `'q'` exists as a valid command)*. Hence, the `-n` option is necessary when `echo`-ing commands to `omxplayer`.

Apart from this 'erroneous handling' of `omxplayer`, the same behavior can be seen when using `cat pipe1 | cat` in stead. After killing the *second* `cat` it is the last (or first following) `echo` which terminates the *first* `cat`.

Comment: Please do not ask questions in an answer. Open a new question for them, or gain enough reputation for commenting first.